# Call WCF from CoreResults Webpart

Tags: 2010, search-results, wcf, query

I am looking to call a WCF service from CoreResults WebPart before the actual Query occurs

We plan on supplementing the Query with information retrieved from the WCF service

Is this possible technically? In ConfigureDataSourceProperties method maybe?

Comment: Is this SharePoint 2010 or SharePoint 2013?

Comment: SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to implement your own custom web part in 2010, subclass the Core Results web part and do any processing prior to running the query. Not hard to do.